# SQL WHERE id is odd?

Tags: php, sql

I was wondering if it were possible to list all of the ODD ID' using PHP and SQL.

I am currently using, which shows all results:

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Users");
```

How would it be possible to list only ODD results using PHP and SQL?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you can do probably faster solution:

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id % 2");
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2bd1/1)

Comment: Even would be: `$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id % 1");` ?

Comment: No, Even will be  `WHERE id % 2 = 0`

Comment: Okay, nice! Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: For Odd it can be also `WHERE id % 2 = 1`, but as shortcut you can just put `WHERE id % 2`.

Comment: I was curious about the speed claims - I did a quick comparison on my machine between 1. `MOD(id, 2) = 1`, 2. `id % 2` and 3. `MOD(id, 2)` with about 4 million records on an InnoDB table. Small difference between 1 and 2 - negligible enough. 2 and 3 are basically the same. Syntactically this is the most succinct answer though imho :)

Comment: I read somewhere using % is a bit faster than using MOD, but I didn't tested it so I used "probably" :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do,

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE MOD(id,2) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE (ID_COLUMN % 2) = 1